# variable is not accumulating correctly SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, function, variables, accumulator

I hope you can help me out with this one, I always get great answers in this site, so this time I come with a weird thing that I found on a SQL script, I'll explain:
I intend to accumulate the whole valor of a column from a query, and when I run the script alone it works perfect, however whenever I try to use the same script within a function or a stored procedure,  my variable gets the valor of the last record.
This is my script:

```
DECLARE @loSetTable TABLE (members VARCHAR(MAX), sorter INT) 
declare @lsEnlarge varchar(max)
set @lsEnlarge=''
SELECT @lsEnlarge=@lsEnlarge +'[menu_item].[h].&[' + rtrim(item_id) + '],' 
FROM cat_objective_item m1 
INNER JOIN cat_menu_item m2 ON (m1.item_id = m2.menu_item_id     AND m2.db_id = 2) 
WHERE objective_id IN (6) 
ORDER BY objective_id,item_id
set @lsEnlarge = substring(@lsEnlarge,1,len(@lsEnlarge)-1)
INSERT INTO @loSetTable VALUES ('SET itemgroup1 AS ''' +  @lsEnlarge  + ' ''  ' ,1)
SELECT * FROM @loSetTable
```

And the output is fine:

```
SET itemgroup1 AS '[menu_item].[h].&[013388],[menu_item].[h].&[015783],[menu_item].[h].&[016049],[menu_item].[h].&[016097],[menu_item].[h].&[016464],[menu_item].[h].&[017802],[menu_item].[h].&[018255],[menu_item].[h].&[018282],[menu_item].[h].&[10150],[menu_item].[h].&[10151] '
```

But when I put the SAME script in a function:

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[mk_mmx_fn_get_kfc_mdx_members] ()            
RETURNS @loSetTable TABLE (members VARCHAR(MAX), sorter INT)            
AS
BEGIN
DECLARE @lsEnlarge AS    VARCHAR(MAX)
SET @lsEnlarge=''

--First group of items
SELECT @lsEnlarge=@lsEnlarge +'[menu_item].[h].&[' + rtrim(item_id) + '],' 
FROM cat_objective_item m1 
INNER JOINcat_menu_item m2 ON (m1.item_id = m2.menu_item_id AND m2.db_id = 2) 
WHERE objective_id IN (6) 
ORDER BY objective_id,item_id
set @lsEnlarge = substring(@lsEnlarge,1,len(@lsEnlarge)-1)
INSERT INTO @loSetTable VALUES ('SET itemgroup1 AS ''' +  @lsEnlarge  + '''' ,1)
RETURN
END
```

I'm getting this:

```
SET itemgroup1 AS '[menu_item].[h].&[10151]'
```

As you can see, Im only getting the last item (which is in the last row) I tried using a store procedure and the result is the same, do you know why this is happening??
Thanks!

Comment: Can you create an executable repro?